# Error 500 when using filters in OData URI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, odata

When I use the simple API : `/api/dashboard`  It works perfectly!

**However, any filter I add, the following error is returned!**

### API URI

`/api/dashboard?$filter=(ProximoAtendimento%20gt%20datetime'2012-11-30'%20and%20ProximoAtendimento%20lt%20datetime'2012-12-02')`

### Error

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Method not found: 'Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SemanticAst.ParameterQueryNode Microsoft.Data.OData.Query.SemanticAst.FilterQueryNode.get_Parameter()'.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.MissingMethodException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.BindFilterQueryNode(FilterQueryNode filterNode)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.Expressions.FilterBinder.Bind(FilterQueryNode filterNode, Type filterType, IEdmModel model, IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.FilterQueryOption.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings, IAssembliesResolver assembliesResolver)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(IQueryable query, ODataQuerySettings querySettings)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.ExecuteQuery(IEnumerable query, HttpRequestMessage request, HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.QueryableAttribute.OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.CallOnActionExecuted(HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpResponseMessage response, Exception exception)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass2.<System.Web.Http.Filters.IActionFilter.ExecuteActionFilterAsync>b__0(HttpResponseMessage response)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass41`2.<Then>b__40(Task`1 t)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThenImpl[TTask,TOuterResult](TTask task, Func`2 continuation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean runSynchronously)"
}
```

**API Controller**

```
[Queryable]
public IQueryable<Pessoa> get()
{
    return _repository.Query<Pessoa>();
}
```

**Packages Versions**

1. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData  ->  *0.2.0-alpha*
2. Microsoft.Data.Edm             ->  *5.1.0*
3. Microsoft.Data.OData           ->  *5.1.0*
4. Microsoft.Data.OData.Contrib   ->  *5.1.0.51119*
5. System.Spatial                 ->  *5.1.0*
6. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi        -> *4.0.20710.0*
7. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client -> *4.1.0-alpha-120809*
8. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core   -> *4.0.20710.0*
9. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData  -> *0.2.0-alpha*
10. Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Web... -> *4.0.20710.0*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MissingMethodExceptions are usually caused by mismatched assembly versions. In your case, it looks like you should be using this NuGet package:

5.1.0.51016-rc2 for Microsoft.Data.OData.Contrib instead of 5.1.0.51119.

See: http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.webapi.odata